# react-native android application first run

Tags: android, react-native

native here is my previous post..I have been finding difficulty to get solution.   [react-native Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498218/react-native-error-unable-to-resolve-module-accessibilityinfo)

Now i have created new project but project loading unlimited time . I press R,R for loading but application blank and it is loading unlimited time. What should I do now your help will be highly appreciable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to resolve module 'AccessibilityInfo', when trying to create release bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756550/unable-to-resolve-module-accessibilityinfo-when-trying-to-create-release-bund)

Answer (score 1):

Is your WLAN connection OK?

I've had the same problem two weeks ago and it seemed to be the WLAN connection for the hot reloading.

My application also was blank and loaded several minutes. So i sat near the Hotspot and then it worked.

Comment: I'm using android studio emulator not external device

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the recent version. You have to use the previous version by using :

react-native init ProjectName --version=0.55.4

The problem should be fixed.