# AccessibilityInfo could not be found within the project

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I got this error while I'm using react-native-datepicker,
got solution but they suggest to downgrade react-native version any other solution please

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "NextDoor",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "push-live-android": "code-push release-react DND-ANDROID android --deploymentName Production",
    "push-live-ios": "code-push release-react DND-IOS ios --deploymentName Production",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "postinstall": "npm i jetifier && npx jetify",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "file:./packages/@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.6.3",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "3.0.3",
    "appcenter": "3.0.0",
    "appcenter-analytics": "3.0.0",
    "appcenter-crashes": "3.0.0",
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "dndcalendar": "file:./packages/dndcalendar",
    "dndserver": "file:./packages/dndserver",
    "dndui": "file:./packages/dndui",
    "faker": "4.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.15.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-braintree-apple-pay": "file:./packages/react-native-braintree-apple-pay",
    "react-native-calendars": "file:./packages/react-native-calendars",
    "react-native-code-push": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-dashed-line": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "file:packages/react-native-datepicker",
    "react-native-deep-link": "^0.2.9",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.1.23",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.6.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.5.1",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.6",
    "react-native-image-picker": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-location": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "file:./packages/react-native-material-dropdown",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-paypal": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.4.0",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-screens": "1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "1.10.3",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "tipsi-stripe": "^7.5.3",
    "validator": "12.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.7.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.7.1",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.8",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

please help, i'm facing it since 3 days unable to find solutions

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `packages/react-native-datepicker/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: AccessibilityInfo could not be found within the project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580180/react-native-bundling-failed-unable-to-resolve-module-accessibilityinfo/52197357 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498218/react-native-error-unable-to-resolve-module-accessibilityinfo

https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-macos/issues/564

Question is already answered in these links

Comment: this problem occurs in react-native-datepicker library, previous question base on react-native version and library so i'm asking it again, kindly help me if you have any idea.

Comment: Then use one another date picker library `react-native-date-picker` instead of ``react-native-datepicker``
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-date-picker this one have more downloads than the other one